# PHP and long running tasks need explanation

Tags: php

I was programming with Ruby On Rails for a while and I used to do long running tasks on a background job like [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), for example processing and image upload to make thumbnails or sending email or maybe interacting with an external API etc... all those tasks are known to tied up the server! but when I come to PHP I don't see people doing those things on the background, every thing I see is done directly !

Doesn't this affect the performance ? can someone explain to me please ?

Comment: Usually when it comes to sending emails etc I tend to look for a queue system and I have been using beanstalkd for a while and it works well. If you are on the laravel framework, it has baked in libraries and it makes it a lot easier.

Comment: Sending email isn't done by Php. Php sends the email to an application which sends the email. Video processing and image processing aren't done by php either.

Comment: @David how that image processing aren't done by php ? how do you do resize images without using your server process ?

Comment: I use http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Comment: @David also I used imagemagick with Rails but this take time and tied up your server process

Comment: Php also comes with the GD library for image processing.

Comment: Gd is also quite slow for image processing.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how Rails work but in PHP it's pretty simple:

You have a site, you send something, PHP does something serverside, you get an answer back.

The "perfomance" depends on how much do you send to the server and what the server sends you back.

Do you want that your site does something on the background while the rest is running? Use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

PHP don't work "in a background", there is  request , phpcode is fired up , and  after php execute code there is  response

If there are  tasks  that  require some  amount  of time to execute, then you use  some quene system . In that  case  there is request, php that adds job to quene, response (and in meantime worker executes job from quene)

For exapmple read  about Rabbit MQ https://www.rabbitmq.com/